# Add Info Icon next DualListBox values in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-duallistbox

I am using Duallist to utilise the multi picklist feature, but I need to add an info icon as well, next to each value of the duallist, and that will have the help text on mouse hover it will be show up.

I am using wrapper to populate options which has currently label, value and help text in it.
Please let me know if its even possible with DualList?
thanks in advance.

I am trying to achieve something like shown in below, the help text icons.
[image]

```
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<lightning:dualListbox name="languages" label= "Select Languages" sourceLabel="Available" selectedLabel="Selected" 
                       fieldLevelHelp="This is a dual listbox" 
                       options="{!v.options}" 
                       onchange="{! c.handleChange }">

</lightning:dualListbox>
```

===========================

```
  ({
handleChange: function (cmp, event) {
    var selectedOptionValue = event.getParam("value");
},

doInit: function (cmp, event, helper) {

    helper.getWrapper(cmp);
    alert(cmp.get("v.options"));
}
```

})

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to be supported by the base component; at-least at the moment, you may have to write your own markup in custom component.

Comment: Use my custom component - has drag and drop and click to move - it's way better and you can customize it. https://github.com/rapsacnz/OrderedListGroup